# php regex save word starting withspecific character

Tags: php, regex

though Id figured this out but need your help
I need to find words that start with fa- in a string
the following works

```
$anchor_css = $item->anchor_css;
if (preg_match_all("/fa\-(\w+)/", $anchor_css, $fa)){   //look for a font awsome class name beginning with fa- if found the lass name is stored in $out[0][0]
    $anchor_css = preg_replace("/fa\-(\w+)/", "", $anchor_css); //remove the font awsome class name starting with fa-
    $anchor_css = preg_replace("/fa/", "", $anchor_css);    //remove the fa prefix from the class
    $anchor_css = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $anchor_css);  //remove multiple spaces and replace with a single space
}
$fa_icon = $fa[0][0] ? '<i class="fa '.implode(' ',$fa[0]).'" ></i>' :'';   //if a font awsome class name exists, create an <i></i> tag
```

the above works for 'test fa fa-info fa-lg'
the result being
anchor_css='test' 
fa_icon= 'fa fa-info fa-lg'
however it does not work for fa-info-circle fa-lg where the results are
anchor_css='test'
fa_icon= 'fa fa-info fa-lg'

I know it is happening because \w does not inclue the hyphen but have no idea how to get around this.  Help please.

Comment: What about [`fa(?:-\w+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/jW8xD5/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not really clear I guess you need  somethings like this in line 3

```
$anchor_css = preg_replace("/fa[-_](\w+)/", "", $anchor_css);
```

*If you'd explain more what do you want to achieve then someone could give you better solution.*

Comment: Sorry, I want to have a regular expression that will extract the font awesome style name (fa-home) from a joints class.what I have now works for fa-info but does not work for days-info-round what I want is a regular expression that will recognise words in the format of fa-info-round without truncating it to fa-info

Comment: OK. I see. Then try this one `(fa-[-a-z]+)` .

you might also use `(fa-[-\w]+)` if you sure it will not capture to much

Comment: Thanks for that Andrew, seems to work a charm.  realised that there are font awsome styles that have numbers (i.e fa-2x) so changed your expression to '(fa-[-a-z0-9]+)' which seems to have done the trick